# Oracle Spatial Index on a View of multiple tables

Tags: oracle, view, spatial-index, oracle-spatial

I have three big tables with same structure (`BATHY_SHC_1, BATHY_SHC_2 and BATHY_SHC_3`), each with a `SDO_GEOMETRY` column “POINT_PP”, the spatial index of each is VALID.
I have made a view on these tables that includes this geometry column (`V_BATHY_SHC`).
I can make spatial request on the view to find all point within a rectangle like this with correct results:

```
SELECT PT_ID, POINT_PP from V_BATHY_SHC
WHERE SDO_RELATE(POINT_PP, MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 32618, null, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,3),MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(635267,5037808, 635277,5037818)), 'mask=anyinteract') = 'TRUE';
```

I have upload a polygon `MASK` in a table `MNE_MASK`, added a line in metadata and created a spatial index (as usual).  It has a valid spatial index. The geometry is in the same SRID (32618).
Then I want to get all points from the view that are within the polygon from the `MNE_MASK` table.  If I made the query on one of the table, I get correct results:

```
SELECT A.PT_ID, A.POINT_PP
FROM BATHY_SHC_1 A, MNE_MASK B
WHERE B.MNE_ID = 1
AND SDO_RELATE(A.POINT_PP, B.MASK, 'mask=ANYINTERACT ') = 'TRUE';
```

But if I made it on the view like this:

```
SELECT A.PT_ID, A.POINT_PP
FROM V_BATHY_SHC A, MNE_MASK B
WHERE B.MNE_ID = 1
AND SDO_RELATE(A.POINT_PP, B.MASK, 'mask=ANYINTERACT ') = 'TRUE';
```

I got this error:

> ORA-13226: interface not supported without a spatial index 
>   ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MD", line 1723 
>   ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MDERR", line 8
>   ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_3GL", line 94

In the past, I’ve always made queries on spatial index of views of multiple tables without problem.
I can make spatial query on both without issue but I can’t make a SDO_RELATE between them… 
Why is this one any different?
Thanks a lot for your insight and help!

Edit:
I've found a quick workaround but it doesn't explain why.
If I swap the two first params in the SDO_RELATE function, the request works.

```
SELECT A.PT_ID, A.POINT_PP
FROM V_BATHY_SHC A, MNE_MASK B
WHERE B.MNE_ID = 1
AND SDO_RELATE(B.MASK, A.POINT_PP, 'mask=ANYINTERACT ') = 'TRUE';
```

Comment: Similar (not resoved) issue on the oracle community forum [link](https://community.oracle.com/message/12930886#12930886).  It might be a bug and oracle doesn't seem to bother correct it as it doesn't affect many person.

Answer (score 0):

In SDO_RELATE, the first parameter is a geometry column in a table, whereas the second is a single geometry. This said, I wonder why your original query works. There you have the view column as the first parameter, just like in the failing query.

Comment: It works because the MNE_MASK table only has 1 result where B.MNE_ID = 1 so the second parameter is a single geometry. (a polygon)